# Django - Grouping querysets by a certain field in template

Tags: python, django

I have a table `Events`, ordered by a field `date`.

I want to print out the events in the template, but using a separate div for each date, e.g.:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>December 30th</h1>
  <!-- div for Event 1 from December 30th -->
  <!-- div for Event 2 from December 30th -->
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>December 31st</h1>
  <!-- div for Event 1 from December 31st -->
  <!-- div for Event 2 from December 31st -->
  <!-- div for Event 3 from December 31st -->
</div>
```

How do I do this?

---

My current solution is to put the Event objects in a dictionary with the date as the key. This has ordering issues and is inelegant and inefficient.

View:

```
events = Event.objects.select_related().all()

events_dict={}
for event in events:
    date=event.date.strftime('%d %B %Y')
    if date in events_dict:
        events_dict[date].append(event) 
    else:
        events_dict[date] = [event]
```

Template:

```
{% for date, events in events_dict.items %}
  <div class="content">
    <h1>{{date}}</h1>
    {% for event in events %}
      {% include "partials/event.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you tried [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag?

Comment: @race1 No I had not and that is just what I was looking for. Thank you. If you post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: thanks, but there is another good answer, accept it :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're looking for the [`{% regroup %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag, which does exactly what you want. It takes a sequence of items (it has to be ordered beforehand, which yours is) and a lookup and groups the sequence by that lookup.

view:

```
events = Event.objects.select_related.all()
```

template:

```
{% regroup events by date as events_by_date %}
{% for date in events_by_date %}
    <div class="content">
    <h1>{{ date.grouper|date:"d F Y" }}</h1>
    {% for event in date.list %}
        {% include "partials/event.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

(Notice that the date format string is different; [the equivalent of `%B` in `strftime` is `F` for the `date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)).

Comment: What if I have to do multiple group by in template?