Django create several columns in a template and fill it with grouped values from QuerySet
I'm pretty a newbie in Web Development, so I've met some difficulties while trying to connect html-templates with Django code.
My plan for a certain page of my projected site is roughly to have a header on above, then lower there are 3 column-shaped containers (left to right, representing different groups) filled with names of members of those groups (one under another, each member in a separate little container with photo, name and description).
Rough example:
|==========================================|
|Characters                                |
|__________________________________________|
|==========================================|
||============||============||============||
|| Faction 1  || Faction 2  || Faction 3  ||
|| |========| || |========| || |========| ||
|| |Member 1| || |Member 1| || |Member 1| ||
|| |________| || |________| || |________| ||
|| |========| || |========| || |========| ||
|| |Member 2| || |Member 2| || |Member 2| ||
|| |________| || |________| || |________| ||
|| |========| ||            || |========| ||
|| |Member 3| ||            || |Member 3| ||
|| |________| ||            || |________| ||
||____________||____________||____________||
|__________________________________________|

I thought that, as I use Django, it would be stupid to hard-code all the members into containers, and there probably are some methods to fill those columns by data from the code. I used for loops.
Here is the template ("core" is a name of the app, templates are located in project/core/templates/core directory):
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<style>
   .layer1 {
    float: left;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 15%
   }
</style>
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div>Characters</div>
<div>
  {% regroup characters by factions as chars_by_factions %}
  <ul>
  {% for factions, chars in chars_by_factions %}
    <div class="layer1">
      <li><h3>{{factions}}</h3>
      <ul>
        {% for char in chars %}
          <li>
          <div>
            <h5>{{char.name}}</h5>
            <h6>{{char.description}}</h6>
          </div>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

File core/models.py:
class Character(models.Model):

    FACTION_CHOICES = (
        ('outers', 'Outer World'),
        ('resistance', 'Resistance'),
        ('neutrals', 'Neutral characters'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, db_index=True, default='')
    faction = models.CharField('Faction', max_length=100, choices=FACTION_CHOICES, default='neutrals')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", blank=True)
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['time_create']
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['time_create'])]

The corresponding view from core/views.py:
def characters(request):
    chars = Character.objects.all()
    factions = [Character.FACTION_CHOICES[i][0] for i in range(len(Character.FACTION_CHOICES))]
    data = {'title': "Characters", 'menu': menu, 'characters': chars, 'factions': factions}
    return render(request, 'core/chars.html', context=data)

I've managed to render the page via regroup tag, but the page showed all the members of all groups in one container, without separating them by different containers according to their groups (factions).
So, my question is - is there an opportunity to create and fill those container columns by cycles with data from QuerySets, and if there is, can you explain me how to do it properly?
If any additional info is necessary, I'm ready to provide it. Thanks a lot for your advices in advance.
P.S.: migration was made, all the members exist in the database.

The method with regroup function I've unsuccessfully tried, was mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678336/django-grouping-querysets-by-a-certain-field-in-template

I am having a bit of an issue following what your problem is, but looking at the code you posted here {% if fac == outers %} I'm guessing nothing is rendered to the page as outers looks like it should be {% if fac.faction == 'outers' %}...I am confused how and why you are passing factions the way you are, you can simply filter in the template based on faction.faction...so looking at that your "grouping" is not helping you, you can automate this with a dict pretty easily, but I feel based on this post you should just if/else based on a total queryset of factions in your template

@ViaTech, thanks for your reply. I've tried to put the factions names in '' and in "", but it returned no result as well. Maybe, I had to put it the way you wrote. I'll try it. Could you please specify the way of ///filter in the template based on faction.faction...///? Because regroup function I've tried didn't help me at all.
